# Postgresql PG_Dump on Master vs Slave are different sizes

Tags: postgresql

I have a backup running on both my master and slave servers using pg_dump, piped into "gzip -c" command. The result file sizes are quite different. My slave backup is 1/3 size of the master backup of the same database.

Replication seems to be running OK. I ran a query of table list with rowcounts and the two databases seem to be the same.

As far as I understand a pg_dump is a text file with copy commands and schema defines. They should be the same size. Am I correct?

PostgreSQL 9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

The backup file is too big to eyeball

Comment: what are the uncompressed sizes and line counts?  `gzcat foo.sql.gz|wc`

Comment: wildly different wc counts. but i just did a table by size and the slave/master databases are so similar. this is incredible. I will do a backup restore of slave soon

Comment: so, restoring the backup taken from slave on another server, shows different table sizes & missing tables altogether. I think the answer is my backups are failing. I will be back.

Comment: looks like my question is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592436/postgresql-error-canceling-statement-due-to-conflict-with-recovery

Comment: Yes, query cancellations could lead to incomplete/failed pg_dump backups.  But they shouldn't be failing silently, so you must not be sufficiently monitoring the exit status and stderr of pg_dump.

Comment: Yes its running through a cron job and I couldn't even find the errors in syslog. I am (relatively) new to this, well to linux mostly. I must read on how to do this. Thank you